# Why are VSCode extensions not working in SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I am using the Remote-SSH extension. When I SSH to a local VM that has Linux, or far away to my uni's pc lab, all my VSCode local extensions don't work, it doesn't show under the extensions pane -> local installed. So doing the keyboard shortcut for one says "command 'extension.advancedNewFile' not found". Why is this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first diagram in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh shows it clearly that only theme/UI extensions remain applicable when VSCode is under remote development mode,

[image]

If you want features of certain extensions, you have to install them on the remote machine (under `EXTENSIONS` | `SSH: MACHINE_NAME - INSTALLED`).